# Django annotate groupings by month

Tags: python, django

I have a very basic model:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    link_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I can create a list of all the entries grouped by date using:

```
Link.objects.values('pub_date').order_by('-pub_date').annotate(dcount=Count('pub_date'))
```

This will naturally group items by day. But what I really want to do is group by month. Is there anyway I can do this using annotate()?

Many thanks,

G

Comment: Not an answer, but you might take a looks at this ticket: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10302

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're on PostgreSQL, the following might work:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Link.objects.extra(select={'month': 'extract( month from pub_date )'}).values('month').annotate(dcount=Count('pub_date'))
```

I'm not sure how portable `extract` is across other databases.

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to work for mySQL also. Except this groups all months across any year. I am trying to get grouped months for each year. But this is a great start so I'll tweak. Thanks again.

Comment: you can slap a filter in there that limits the dates to certain ranges.  `.filter(pub_date__gte=datetime.datetime(fill in date here))`

Comment: using `connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date')` instead of hardcoded extract SQL would made the statement compatible with others backends

Answer (score 14):

```
from django.db import connections
from django.db.models import Count

Link.objects.extra(select={'month': connections[Link.objects.db].ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'pub_date')}).values('month').annotate(dcount=Count('pub_date'))
```

Comment: Note that you must also import `from django.db.models import Count`

Answer (score 3):

To add, as an alternative for using `extra()`: since Django 1.8, you can also use conditional expressions.

```
>>> year_overview = Link.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year).aggregate(
    jan=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=0, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    feb=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=1, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    mar=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=2, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    apr=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=3, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    may=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=4, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    jun=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=5, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    jul=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=6, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    aug=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=7, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    sep=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=8, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    oct=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=9, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    nov=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=10, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    dec=Sum(
        Case(When(created__month=11, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
)

>>> year_overview
{'mar': None, 'feb': None, 'aug': None, 'sep': 95, 'apr': 1, 'jun': None, 'jul': None, 'jan': None, 'may': None, 'nov': 87, 'dec': 94, 'oct': 100}
```

Comment: With the latest Django version I guess this is the solution recommeded

Answer (score 3):

I've read that `.extra()` will be deprecated in the future.  They are suggesting to instead use `Func` objects.  And there is one for extracting a month without using a painful `Case` statement.

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth
Link.objects.all().annotate(pub_date_month=ExtractMonth('pub_date'))
```