# Date hiearchy of items in django

Tags: django

I have a model with datetime field. I want to get a table with three columns as, year, month and number of items in time span. And I also want to order them from newest to oldest. What I want to get is something like this:

```
2011 August 4
2011 March 7
```

How do you suggest I should do that?

### Edit

I ended up doing something like this, I am not sure if it is best way to go though.

```
query_set = Post.objects.all()
years = query_set.dates("pub_date","year")
date_hierarchy = {}
for year in years:
    date_hierarchy[year] = {}
    months = query_set.filter(pub_date__year=year.year).dates("pub_date","month")
    for month in months:
        date_hierarchy[year][month] = query_set.filter(pub_date__year=month.year,pub_date__month=month.month).count()
```

Then, in template:

```
{% for year, month_dict in date_hierarchy.items %}
    {% for month,post_count in month_dict.items %}
        <li><a href="{% url arsiv_month month.year month.month %}">{{ month|date:"Y E" }} [{{ post_count }}]</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Django and Python both let you split out dates into their parts, so maybe you don't actually need the 3 columns and could go with just the 1. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have blog post, I am trying to create an archive part in homepage, where I will show month by month links, and in link texts, I will give how many post on that month in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause. django supports this. for example: [Django annotate groupings by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543379/django-annotate-groupings-by-month) (the second response in the question that I linked seems more portable than the accepted answer).

Comment: I am not trying to get date ordered models, I am trying to get, date ordered dates with item counts with them. I added some more information in original post.

Comment: The link you provided looks like the answer, however, I didn't understand a thing about it.