# Django ORM, group by day

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I am trying to group products by DAY, however date_created is a datetime field.

```
Product.objects.values('date_created') \
               .annotate(available=Count('available_quantity'))
```

returns:

```
[
    {'date_created': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 14, 13, 3, 6), 'available': 1},
    {'date_created': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 14, 17, 12, 9), 'available': 1},
    ...
]
```

I want:

```
[
    {'date_created': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 14), 'available': 2}, ...
]
```

**edit:** database backend MYSQL

Comment: yes I want something like [{'today': 17}, {'yesterday': 21}, etc]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543379/django-annotate-groupings-by-month) try this for MySQL

```
from django.db.models import Count

Product.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date( date_created )'}).values('day') \
               .annotate(available=Count('date_created'))
```

Comment: This was helpful but I've had to clear the default ordering with an explicit order_by() in between values() and annotate(). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by. Thanks!

Comment: Weird... i still have multiple fields not being grouped in the count, even with the same date... i tried the sollution bellow with to_char and changed my DB from sqlite to postgres, but when running available=Count('date_created') he is considering the datetime

Answer (score 6):

Similar approach from [San4ez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10154412/1476885)'s answer, but returning dates as 'YYYY-MM-DD' instead of 'datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD)':

```
Product.objects.extra(select={'day': "TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY-MM-DD')"})
               .values('day') \
               .order_by('day') \
               .annotate(available=Count('date_created'))
```

Comment: The queryset returned is in a more readable format with your answer. Thanks. It is a better than the one suggested by @San4ez

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.4, you could use `.dates('date_created', 'day')` instead of `.values()`.

Try this code snippet:

```
Product.objects.annotate(available=Count('available_quantity')) \
  .dates('date_created', 'day')
```

This *should* return:

```
[
    {'date_created': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 14), 'available': 2}, ...
]
```

Comment: sounds close but I get a list with dates only:
[datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 10, 0, 0)]

Comment: Try .annotate() before creating the DateQuerySet using .dates.

Comment: same for me, only dates

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Product.objects.extra(select={'day': "TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY-MM-DD')"})\
                .values('day')\
                .order_by('day')\
                .annotate(bets=Count('date_created'))
```

Answer (score 0):

By following the answer of [San4ez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455833/san4ez) and the changes from [Zanon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1476885/zanon)

For me i had to make a workaround to work with Postgres or Sqlite, since the Count() function will consider the datetime field, doesn't matter if you going to create a "day" input just with the date because the date_created is still holding the time information, so multiple records with time on it wont be merged and counted up, after trying many things deferents i reached that way of skipping the time

Django 2.2

```
from django.db.models import Count

# Change date() to to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD') if using Postgres
Product.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date( date_created )'})\
    .values('day') \
    .order_by('date_created__date')\
    .annotate(available=Count('date_created__date'))
```