# Format timestamp in Django query in values

Tags: sql, django, group-by, django-queryset

I am trying to use a Dajngo QuerySet  where I have to format time_stamp field in `.values ('time_stamp')`.

In PostgreSql I can dot like this:

```
GROUP BY time_stamp::date
```

I have to do this because in the date column the format (*2018-01-22 00:00:28+01*) show time as well and I want know the average of the filed only in ONE day.

**So my main question how can I create a query in Django which equal with this PostgreSQL query.**

```
SELECT avg(field) FROM table GROUP BY time_stamp::date
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of PostgreSQL, but `::date` looks like a database function?. Have you had a look at the `Func()` query expressions? [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions). Or maybe [EXTRACT/TRUNC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#date-functions) will work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154227/django-orm-group-by-day):

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(day=RawSQL('date(timestamp)', ())).values('day').annotate(Avg('price')).order_by('day')
```

Is that what you want? The order_by is not necessary

Comment: Eventually I used TruncDay and it helped me, but your answer is also wotking well.