# Using extra with SortedDict in Django

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying to add an extra field to a select statement in django, In which I want to use a varying format string.

The following results in:
**Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 4 supplied.**

```
select=SortedDict([(
    "groupkey", 
    "strftime('%s', datetime(time, 'utc'),'localtime')")]),
select_params=(
    "%m"
)
```

This way I get:
**unsupported format character 'm' (0x6d) at index 19** when using %m as a format string. It seems to work when using %%m as a format string but I don't consider this as a nice solution.

```
select={
    "groupkey":"strftime('" + self.__formatstring + "', datetime(time, 'utc'),'localtime')"
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to group the values in the table either by minute, hour, day, month or year. Using plain SQL I did this by using the sqlite built in strftime function. (e.g. GROUP BY strftime("%m", time) would group by month). For some reason the "%" symbols seem to screw up the django orm module, and I'd have to use "%%m" (which I don't want to do)

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543379/django-annotate-groupings-by-month