# Django: grouping and counting by day

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, postgresql

I need to group and count items by date. I got it on sqlite with the followint:

```
Books.objects.filter(state="new").extra({"published_at": "date(published_at)"}).values("published_at").annotate(counter=Count("pk"))
```

But the use of extra() with sql statement cannot be portable on other dbms. For example the above doesn't work on mysql.
How i can have a working query for sqlite, postgresql and mysql?

Comment: How are you counting by date. It seems you are counting by pk which always will be 1. Also why do you need `"date(published_at)"`. Django's `Datetime` field already gives a datetime object so no need to convert to a date again.

Comment: Because published_at is a timestamp and i need to count Books by day.

Answer (score 1):

<del>If you want a database agnostic query, than don't use extra().
    books = Books.objects.filter(state="new")
         .order_by('published_at', )
         .values("published_at", ) 
         .annotate(count=Count("published_at__day"))</del>

Accessing a date__day (published_at__day) fails with:

> FieldError: Join on field 'date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'day'
>   for the lookup type?

If rewrote [Django annotate groupings by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543379/django-annotate-groupings-by-month) to grouping by day.

```
Book.objects.all().extra(select={'day': 'extract( day from date )'}).values('day').annotate(num=Count('date')).order_by()
```

You may want to replace .all() with a .filter(year=some_year) because this will span mutiple years.

`Extract` is confirmed to work on MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Updated my answer. But I'm still not sure if I completely understand what try to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: What does the SQLite .extra({"published_at": "date(published_at)"}) do? Convert a string to a date?

Comment: yes, it converts to date. as i said i need the counter of books published per day

Comment: This code gets the following error: Join on field 'published_at' not permitted. Did you misspell 'day' for the lookup type?